# Scopes and nested namespaces for C#

Tags: c#, namespaces, nested, scopes

I have a project in C# where there are two namespaces defined in seperate files where one is the subset of the other:

```
namespace RSSTimerJob

namespace RSSTimerJob.Features.RSSFilter
```

I have a static class called `Toolbox` which belongs to the 1st namespace. Now when I try to call the protected static variables of the `Toolbox` class from a custom class in the 2nd namespace, I get an error saying its inaccessible due to its protection level.

Why does it give me this error. Since the 2nd namespace is a subset of the 1st, doesnt that mean that making the variable protected should allow the 2nd namespace's class to see it?

Setting the variables to public of course, makes this error go away but I am just curious :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`protected` is not the keyword you want to use.

`internal` allows access to members of classes to other classes *in the same assembly*.

In C#, `protected` allows access to base members to classes that derive from that base. You *might* be thinking of Java, where `protected` is slightly different, in that it grants access to subclasses plus classes within the same package. To get roughly that same behavior in C#, you would use the combination `protected internal`, which is inclusive of `protected` and `internal`, granting access for derived classes *as well as* access for classes in the same assembly.

Comment: protected internal is the intersection of protected and internal, as you said. This mains access is granted only to derived classes that are also in the same assembly.

Comment: A intersect B means items in A and also in B, doesn't it? So protected internal means access to both protected (derived class) and internal (same assembly).

Comment: You know, I completely misworded it. I apologize. At any rate, it's not as restrictive as you describe, but I may have classified it incorrectly. Will fix.

Comment: The right way to think about it is that the natural state of a member is "private". "protected" weakens that. "internal" weakens that.  "protected internal" weakens it twice.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Although I have programmed in C, and C++, I am mostly a Java programmer hence the confusion with the 'protected' keyword. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`protected` means that the thing is available to the class itself and derived **classes**.

I wouldn't go berserk with namespaces though.  They're useful if you've got lot of things to put in them and these things are different enough.  Here's some [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on namespace best-practices.

Answer (score 0):

"protected" means that that member can be accessed from the same class, or from derived classes. But that doesn't allow other members of the same namespace to access that member.

What you are looking for is probably "internal", that means the member can be accessed by code in the same assembly.

By the way you can add more members to the same namespace from a different assembly.